# Add flat rate shipping fees in Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

> Hi ,  I am working in **Woocommerce** and I want to add shipping fees $7 on
>   the total order that less than $50 .
>
> **Could you please help me on this issue ?**

Comment: Sorry, but what does "the total order that little than $50" mean? Do you mean you want to add a fee to orders that are less than $50?

Comment: Yes the orders that are less than $50 I want to add $7 shipping fess on .

Comment: you can set up minimum amount in settings of flat rate

Comment: @MujeebuRahman You can add minimum amount per product but I want to add per total amount

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Costs option under WC settings

The Cost field allows you to charge a flat rate per item, a percentage based cost or a minimum fee.

Available placeholders:

```
[qty] – Number of products in the cart
[fee] – An additional fee. This fee has two optional arguments.
    percent – A percentage based on total order cost.
    min_fee – A minimum amount. Useful when using percentages.
```

Examples

```
10 + ( 2 * [qty] ) – A base shipping cost of $10 plus $2 for each item in the cart.
20 + [fee percent="10" min_fee="4"] – A base shipping cost of $20 plus 10% of the order total, which is at least $4.
```

Check [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/flat-rate-shipping/#section-2)